# Loop - Calculated last element different

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Hi everyone (sry for the bad title),

I have a loop in which I can get a rounding difference every time I pass. I would like to cumulate them and add it to the last record of my result.

```
var cumulatedRoundDifference = 0m;
var resultSet = Enumerable.Range(0, periods)
    .Select(currentPeriod => {
        var value = this.CalculateValue(currentPeriod);    
        var valueRounded = this.CommercialRound(value);

        // Bad part :(
        cumulatedRoundDifference += value - valueRounded; 
        if (currentPeriod == periods - 1)
           valueRounded = this.CommercialRound(value + valueRounded);

    return valuesRounded;
}
```

At the moment the code of my opinion is not so nice.
Is there a pattern / algorithm for such a thing or is it somehow clever with Linq, without a variable outside the loop?

many Greetings

Comment: Do you mean to `return valueRounded;` without the `s`?

Comment: cumulatedRoundDifference does not seem to be part part of the returned value.

Comment: @Magnus The cumulation is actually main thing of the result at the end, as it changed after running the loop. I have another question. Why, for the last value (currentPeriod == periods - 1) the routing is done like this "again" ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing two things - rounding everything, and calculating the total rounding error.

You *could* remove the variable outside the lambda, but then you would need 2 queries.

```
var baseQuery = Enumerable.Range(0, periods)
   .Select(x => new { Value = CalculateValue(x), ValueRounded = CommercialRound(x) });
var cumulateRoundDifference = baseQuery.Select(x => x.Value - x.ValueRounded).Sum();
// LINQ isn't really good at doing something different to the last element
var resultSet = baseQuery.Select(x => x.ValueRounded).Take(periods - 1).Concat(new[] { CommercialRound(CalculateValue(periods - 1) + CommericalRound(periods - 1)) });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a pattern / algorithm for such a thing or is it somehow clever with Linq, without a variable outside the loop?

I don't quite agree with what you're trying to accomplish. You're trying to accomplish two very different tasks, so why are you trying to merge them into the same iteration block? The latter (handling the last item) isn't even supposed to be an iteration.

For readability's sake, I suggest splitting the two off. It makes more sense and doesn't require you to check if you're on the last loop of the iteration (which saves you some code and nesting).

---

While I don't quite understand the calculation in and of itself, I can answer the algorithm you're directly asking for (though I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, which I'll address later in the answer).

```
var allItemsExceptTheLastOne = allItems.Take(allItems.Count() - 1);

foreach(var item in allItemsExceptTheLastOne)
{
    // Your logic for all items except the last one
}

var theLastItem = allItems.Last();

// Your logic for the last item
```

This is in my opinion a cleaner and more readable approach. I'm not a fan of using lambda methods as mini-methods with a less-than-trivial readability. This may be subjective and a matter of personal style.

---

On rereading, I think I understand the calculation better, so I've added an attempt at implementing it, while still maximizing readability as best I can:

```
// First we make a list of the values (without the sum)

var myValues = Enumerable
                    .Range(0, periods)
                    .Select(period => this.CalculateValue(period))
                    .Select(period => period - this.CommercialRound(period))
                    .ToList();

// myValues = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ]

myValues.Add(myValues.Sum());

// myValues = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6 ]
```

This follows the same approach as the algorithm I first suggested: iterate over the iteratable items, and then separately handle the last value of your intended result list.

Note that I separated the logic into two subsequent `Select` statements as I consider it the most readable (no excessive lambda bodies) and efficient (no duplicate `CalculateValue` calls) way of doing this. If, however, you are more concerned about performance, e.g. when you are expecting to process massive lists, you may want to merge these again.

I suggest that you always try to default to writing code that favors readability over (excessive) optimization; and only deviate from that path when there is a clear need for additional optimization (which I cannot decide based on your question).

---

On a second reread, I'm not sure you've explained the actual calculation well enough, as `cumulatedRoundDifference` is not actually used in your calculations, but the code seems to suggest that its value should be important to the end result.